# How to extend a complex type in a different namespace without changing name

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an existing namespace that I cannot change.  I need to add elements to a complex type such that the resulting XML looks like this:

Original XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Book xmlns="http://bookshop.com">
  <Author>Frank Herbert</Author>
  <Title>Dune</Title>
</Book>
```

New XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Book xmlns="http://bookshop.com" 
      xlmns:custom="http://custombookshop.com">
  <Author>Frank Herbert</Author>
  <Title>Dune</Title>
  <custom:Publisher>Ace</custom:Publisher>
</Book>
```

I have requirements that the custom elements must appear as above with the namespace prefix, and that the complex type name must not change.

Here is the original XSD and the new XSD I've attempted using redefine.  Will this work, or is there a better way to accomplish this?  Thanks in advance for your advice.

Original XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           xmlns="http://bookshop.com" 
           targetNamespace="bookshop.com">
  <xs:complexType name="Book">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Author" type="String32" 
                    minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="Title" type="String32" 
                    minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

My attempted new XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           xmlns="http://custombookshop.com" 
           targetNamespace="custombookshop.com">
  <xs:redefine schemaLocation="http://bookshop.com">
    <xs:complexType name="Book">
      <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="Book">
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Publisher" type="String32" 
                        minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
      </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:redefine>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: When you say you "have [a] requirement ... that the complex type name must not change", you mean what?

Comment: If you need a *different* namespace you can't use `xs:redefine`. You probably want to use `xs:import`.

Comment: By saying "have [a] requirement ... that the complex type name must not change", I meant that the name of XML with the custom field must also be "Book", it cannot be a different name like "BookExtension".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your *original* schema should declare the `sequence` inside the `complexType`:

```
<xs:complexType name="Book">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Author" type="String32" 
            minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="Title" type="String32" 
            minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

It should also declare the `targetNamespace` equal to the default `xmlns` namespace, and include the attribute `elementFormDefault="qualified"` so you can use unqualified elements in your instance. The schema below (to which I added an `element` declaration and a `simpleType` declaration) validates your original XML:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns="http://bookshop.com" 
    targetNamespace="http://bookshop.com"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:complexType name="Book">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Author" type="String32" 
                minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xs:element name="Title" type="String32" 
                minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="Book" type="Book"/>

    <xs:simpleType name="String32">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string"></xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Assuming that the schema above as your *original* schema, you can *redefine* the `Book` complex type in a new schema *with the same target namespace* as your original schema. If it needs to contain a `Publisher` element from another namespace, you have to declare it in a third schema. In a schema with the same target namespace as your original schema, you can redefine the `Book` type like this (assuming your original schema is in `bookshop.xsd`:

```
<xs:redefine schemaLocation="bookshop.xsd">
    <xs:complexType name="Book">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="Book">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element ref="cs:Publisher" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:redefine>
```

For that to work you have to import the schema where the `Publisher` element is declared. Suppose it is declared in this schema, with the `http://custombookshop.com` namespace:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://custombookshop.com" 
    xmlns:bs="http://bookshop.com" 
    targetNamespace="http://custombookshop.com"> 

    <xs:import namespace="http://bookshop.com" schemaLocation="bookshop.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="Publisher" type="bs:String32" />

</xs:schema>
```

You can then import it into your redefined schema:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://bookshop.com" 
    targetNamespace="http://bookshop.com"
    xmlns:cs="http://custombookshop.com"> 

    <xs:import schemaLocation="custombookshop.xsd" namespace="http://custombookshop.com"/>

    <xs:redefine schemaLocation="bookshop.xsd">
        ...
    </xs:redefine>

</xs:schema>
```

And now, you can validate your second XML file using the redefined schema.

Comment: Thanks for you comment.  Unfortunately the existing original schema  cannot be modified.  I noted in my question above that the original namespace cannot be modified, but I should have made that clearer.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: The suggestion I made for the original schema is actually a correction, since you can't place a sequence inside a `<complexContent>`. If the one you posted is just an example, I assume the real one is correct and doesn't need this.

Comment: The redefined schema does not modify the namespace. It *can't*, since redefine requires that the target namespace be the same. But your second instance has an element from another namespace. That's defined in a third schema above, with a different namespace.

Comment: I can't assume anything about your actual files, but if you use the schemas described here, your second instance will validate against the last schema.

Comment: Thanks for the correction on the original bookshop.xsd, yes it was just an example.    So if I understand correctly, I can create my own version of the original xsd bookshop.xsd, but my version imports my custom namespace and redefines the types I need.  I see how that would work, I will give it a try.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Assuming that `bookshop.xsd` is the *original* XSD you can't change, you would create two new schemas: one which I called `custombookshop.xsd` with a *different* namespace (`http://custombookshop.com`) for the elements that belong to another namespace (such as your `Publisher`) - this one is *importing* the `bookshop.xsd` just because it relies on one of the types defined there; the second schema *redefines* a type in the *same namespace*, and it also imports the *custom* schema (which is in another namespace) because you are adding an element defined there to your new type.