# How to Import XSD and add extension to Element

Tags: xsd

EDIT:  Based on my reading I think I need to try something like this... [How to extend a complex type in a different namespace without changing name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24043756/how-to-extend-a-complex-type-in-a-different-namespace-without-changing-name)  I have yet to try but will update if I have success with this method...

So I have a project where I have a massive XSD that is provided by a third party and I'd like to add my own elements and attributes to the XSD.  I would like to add an element to the substitutiongroup="SpecificResource" and also an attribute.

Let's call the larger third party xsd "base.xsd", I've stripped it down to the parts that I believe are relevant to the example.

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.base.com"
           xmlns="http://www.base.com"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

  <xs:element abstract="true" name="SpecificResource" type="SpecificResource"/>
  <xs:complexType abstract="true" name="SpecificResource">
      <xs:anyAttribute namespace="##other" processContents="lax"/>
  </xs:complexType>

 <xs:element name="FileSpec">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" ref="Disposition"/>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" ref="NetworkHeader"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="Example" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
            <xs:anyAttribute namespace="##other" processContents="lax"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```

And my custom xsd named "Custom.xsd"

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:cus="https://www.custom.com"
           xmlns="http://www.base.com"
           targetNamespace="https://www.custom.com"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:import namespace="https://www.base.com" schemaLocation="base.xsd"/>

    <xs:attribute name="URL" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="customattribute" type="xs:NMTOKEN"/>

    <xs:element name="SpecRes1" substitutionGroup="SpecificResource" type="cus:SpecRes1"/>

    <xs:complexType name="SpecRes1">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="SpecificResource">
                <xs:attribute ref="cus:customattribute"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name ="fullfilespec">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="FileSpec">
                <xs:attribute ref="URL" use="optional"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
```

However, right now I get "Undefined complexType 'http://www.base.com:FileSpec' is used as a base for complex type extension."  I don't understand why as I believe Filespec is defined in the base.xsd.

Am I doing something wrong when it comes to importing?

A followup question is whether there is a way to make the Imported XSD not require prefixes, while making the items I have added require the namespace prefix (cus:)  Currently I have been able to add my element to the "SpecificResource" but my element appears to be defined in the base.xsd namespace which I don't think is what I want.  When I am using the XSD I end up with a file that is valid without putting prefixes on my added elements which makes it hard to differentiate what I've added versus what already existed. (I am generating a class file from the xsd, and serializing and deserializing data with it.)

I took this approach of importing the base xsd so that I don't need to touch the base.xsd file but is it not possible to extend on imported elements in your custom namespace?

I originally was adding to the base.xsd and importing my custom.xsd but it's becoming very tedious to keep adding to the base.xsd while also making adding to the substitutiongroup SpecificResource difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't extend a `xs:element` you can only extend an `xs:complexType`.
And you can reference an attribute that is defined in the `xs:schema` element (i.e. a root attribute), but you must qualify it using its targetnamespace.
Also the namespace in the `xs:import` must match the source xsd file (yours miss-match http/https).

[image]

[image]

**Base.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- Created with Liquid Studio 2020 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com) -->
<xs:schema xmlns="http://www.base.com" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.base.com" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="SpecificResource" type="SpecificResource" abstract="true" />
    <xs:complexType abstract="true" name="SpecificResource">
        <xs:anyAttribute namespace="##other" processContents="lax" />
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="FileSpec">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Disposition" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xs:element name="NetworkHeader" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="Example" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
        <xs:anyAttribute namespace="##other" processContents="lax" />
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

**Main.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--Created with Liquid Studio 2020 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com)-->
<xs:schema xmlns:cus="https://www.custom.com" xmlns="http://www.base.com" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="https://www.custom.com" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:import schemaLocation=".\base.xsd" namespace="http://www.base.com" />
    <xs:attribute name="URL" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:attribute name="customattribute" type="xs:NMTOKEN" />
    <xs:element name="SpecRes1" type="cus:SpecRes1" substitutionGroup="SpecificResource" />
    <xs:complexType name="SpecRes1">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="SpecificResource">
                <xs:attribute ref="cus:customattribute" />
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="fullfilespec">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="FileSpec">
                <xs:attribute ref="cus:URL" use="optional" />
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Oops about the mismatch in http vs https, that was just a typo from editing my example, but thanks for noticing as those kinds of mistakes are easy to overlook.  You answered my other question about Elements not being extendable like ComplexTypes are so it sounds like I'm in a bit of a bind of not having a solution that's achievable without editing my main xsd file that I was hoping on importing.  Thanks for the reply though as well as lessons on XSD.