# Extend & redefine an XSD in Enterprise Architect

Tags: xsd, enterprise-architect

I'm creating an XML schema definition that extends an existing XSD (which was generated from a model built in Enterprise Architect) - I'm not permitted to modify the text of the existing XSD for copyright reasons, but I can reference it. The core aim is to be able to create elements from the original schema but add new sub-elements to them (the new sub-elements will be defined in a new namespace).

I've done what I needed to do by hand-crafting a new XSD based on the solution from [How to extend a complex type in a different namespace without changing name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24043756/how-to-extend-a-complex-type-in-a-different-namespace-without-changing-name) which uses `xs:import` and `xs:redefine` to refer to and extend the original schema - so far so good! For completeness, the solution required two XSDs to define the new elements and then redefine the old namespace.

new.xsd:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="new-namespace" 
    xmlns:bs="old-namespace" 
    targetNamespace="new-namespace"> 
    <xs:import namespace="old-namespace" schemaLocation="old.xsd"/>    
    <xs:element name="myElement" type="bs:OldCustomType" />
</xs:schema>
```

and main.xsd (which is the definition file you can reference to validate XML etc.):

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="old-namespace" 
    targetNamespace="old-namespace"
    xmlns:new="new-namespace"> 
    <xs:import schemaLocation="new.xsd" namespace="new-namespace"/>
    <xs:redefine schemaLocation="old.xsd">
        ...
        <!-- Modifications go here -->
        ...
    </xs:redefine>
</xs:schema>
```

However I now need to similarly extend the original schema's WADL, also generated from the EA model. It would also be preferable to have an EA model to generate documentation etc. if possible, hence I'm trying to replicate the same schema functionality in EA. Unfortunately I'm not sure that the matching solution is possible in EA as [this link](https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/16.0/modeling_domains/model_xsd.html) indicates that the `redefine` XML schema construct has not been implemented in EA.

I was wondering if anyone has any alternative ways of achieving the same import-redefine type of functionality in EA (i.e. that doesn't rely on `redefine`)?

Comment: Are you sure you need to import/redefine? Can't you simply import the XSD in EA, update the model, and then generate a new XSD from EA?