# How to extend complex Type in namespace without changing the target namespace

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

Referencing this: [Other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24043756/how-to-extend-a-complex-type-in-a-different-namespace-without-changing-name)
I am trying to do basically the same thing as the OP from this other post; to extend a complexType with my own added attributes, without changing the primary namespace. I tried following the answer reply as closely as possible but am not having success.

Following the last post I created 4 files: 3 xsd's and 1 xml.

original.xsd

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns="http://bookshop.com" 
targetNamespace="http://bookshop.com"
elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xs:complexType name="Book">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Author" type="String32" 
            minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="Title" type="String32" 
            minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="Book" type="Book"/>

<xs:simpleType name="String32">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string"></xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

added.xsd

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
elementFormDefault="qualified"
xmlns="http://custombookshop.com" 
xmlns:bs="http://bookshop.com" 
targetNamespace="http://custombookshop.com"> 

<xs:import namespace="http://bookshop.com" schemaLocation="original.xsd"/>
<xs:element name="Publisher" type="bs:String32" />
</xs:schema>
```

newMainfile.xsd

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
elementFormDefault="qualified"
xmlns="http://bookshop.com"
targetNamespace="http://bookshop.com"
xmlns:cs="http://custombookshop.com">

<xs:import schemaLocation="added.xsd" namespace="http://custombookshop.com"/>
<xs:redefine schemaLocation="original.xsd">
    <xs:complexType name="Book">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="Book">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element ref="cs:Publisher" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:redefine>
</xs:schema>
```

test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Book xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
elementFormDefault="qualified"
xmlns="http://bookshop.com"
targetNamespace="http://bookshop.com"
xs:schemaLocation="newMainfile.xsd"
xmlns:cs="http://custombookshop.com">
<Author>Frank Herbert</Author>
<Title>Dune</Title>
<cs:Publisher>Ace</cs:Publisher>
</Book>
```

However, this does not produce something I can validate. After adding the xml and xsd's to the working directory of my c# project running the following code does not work.

```
var path = @"test.xml";
        XmlSchemaSet schema = new XmlSchemaSet();
        schema.Add("", "newMainfile.xsd");
        XmlReader rd = XmlReader.Create(path);
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(rd);
        doc.Validate(schema, ValidationEventHandler);
```

An exception occurs with

> "System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaException: 'The targetNamespace parameter
> '' should be the same value as the targetNamespace
> 'http://bookshop.com' of the schema.'"

Substituting the namespace "http://bookshop.com" for the "" in schema.Add("", "newMainfile.xsd");
also does not validate and instead produces error.

> System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaException: ''SchemaLocation' must successfully resolve if <'redefine'> contains any child other than <'annotation'>.'

Am I missing some sort of vital step? Appreciate your time and responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue is that the default resolver of the `XmlSchemaSet` class doesn't actually support relative file paths. To get this to work you can either:

- Change the *schemaLocation* attribute to point to a full file path like `<xs:redefine schemaLocation="file://C:/temp/whatever/original.xsd">` or
- Pre-load all required `XmlSchema`s through the use of an instance of `XmlPreloadedResolver`.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Schema;
// you will need this namespace for the preloaded resolver class
using System.Xml.Resolvers;

void Main()
{
    // put all your XSD files to a single folder path
    var basePath = @"C:\temp\so76168480";
    var path = Path.Combine(basePath, @"test.xml");
    // see method definition below 
    var preloader = PreLoadXmlSchemas(basePath);
    XmlSchemaSet schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet() {
        XmlResolver = preloader
    };
    
    schemaSet.Add("http://bookshop.com", Path.Combine(basePath, "newMainfile.xsd"));
    
    XmlReader rd = XmlReader.Create(path);
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(rd);
    
    doc.Validate(schemaSet, (i, e) => {
        // should be ok
    });
}

public static XmlPreloadedResolver PreLoadXmlSchemas(string directoryPath)
{
    if (directoryPath == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(directoryPath));

    var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(directoryPath);
    FileInfo[] additionalXsds = directoryInfo.GetFiles("*.xsd");

    var xmlPreloadedResolver = new XmlPreloadedResolver();

    foreach (FileInfo xsd in additionalXsds)
    {
        xmlPreloadedResolver.Add(new Uri($"file://{xsd.FullName}"), File.OpenRead(xsd.FullName));
    }
    
    return xmlPreloadedResolver;
}
```

The [XmlPreloadedResolver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.resolvers.xmlpreloadedresolver?view=netframework-4.8.1) is available on .NET Framework, .NET Core and .NET 5+ so it should be immediately available to use.